# Windows NamedPipe on 2012 limits the data read to 64k

Tags: windows, named-pipes, windows-server-2012

I have 2 process communicating via named pipes using overlapped i/o . On Window 2012 r2 it has been observed that the the data read at the reading end of the file is limited to 64k. If the client process runs on a Windows 7 64 bit, client is able to get the data even if more than 64k.

```
while( TRUE ) 
        {

            // Read from the pipe. 

            BOOL fSuccess ;
            DWORD cbRead ;
            OVERLAPPED osRx ;
            memset( &osRx, 0, sizeof( osRx ) ) ;
            osRx.hEvent = m_hRxEvent ;
            // create a new message object
            m_pMsg = new CInMsg( 64*1024 ) ; // This is the message size and can be changed via registry
            fSuccess = ReadFile(
                                  m_hPipe,                  // pipe handle              
                                  m_pMsg->GetDataPtr(),         // buffer to receive reply  
                                  m_pMsg->GetBuffLength(),  // size of buffer           
                                  &cbRead,                      // number of bytes read     
                                  &osRx                         // overlapped           
                               );
            if(!fSuccess)
            {

                dwError = GetLastError() ;

                if( ERROR_IO_PENDING == dwError )
                {

                    fSuccess = GetOverlappedResult(
                                                    m_hPipe,    // handle to pipe       
                                                    &osRx,          // OVERLAPPED structure 
                                                    &cbRead,        // bytes transferred    
                                                    INFINITE        // wait 
                                                  ) ;          
                    if(!fSuccess)
                    {
                        dwError = GetLastError() ;
                    }
                }
            }


            if( !fSuccess )
            {
                while( ERROR_MORE_DATA == dwError )
                {

                    DWORD dwBytesLeft ;

                    // find out how much left

                    PeekNamedPipe( 
                                    m_hPipe,                    
                                    NULL,                           
                                    0,  
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL,
                                    &dwBytesLeft                    
                                 ) ; 


                    if( 0 == dwBytesLeft )
                    {
                        // break out as no data left

                        fSuccess = TRUE ;

                        break ;
                    }   





                    // Use the dwBytesLeft and create a new  CInMsg (pTempTmsMsg)
                    // Copy data from old to new Object
                    //delete old message


                    OVERLAPPED osTmpRx ;
                    memset( &osTmpRx, 0, sizeof( osTmpRx ) ) ;
                    osTmpRx.hEvent = m_hRxEvent ;
                    DWORD cbTmpRead ;

                    // now do another read

                    dwError = NO_ERROR ;

                    fSuccess = ReadFile(
                                          m_hPipe,                  
                                          m_pMsg->GetAppendBuffer(),    
                                          m_pMsg->GetAppendLength(),    
                                          &cbTmpRead,                   
                                          &osTmpRx                      
                                       );

                    if(!fSuccess)
                    {

                        dwError = GetLastError() ;

                        if( ERROR_IO_PENDING == dwError )
                        {

                            fSuccess = GetOverlappedResult(
                                                            m_hPipe,    
                                                            &osTmpRx,       
                                                            &cbTmpRead,     
                                                            INFINITE        
                                                          ) ;          
                            if(!fSuccess)
                            {
                                dwError = GetLastError() ;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    m_pMsg->SetMsgLength( m_pMsg->GetMsgLength() + cbTmpRead ) ;

                    // set message size

                    cbRead += cbTmpRead ;

                }
            }
```

This is the main loop of the client.
The Pipe is created in Message Mode and the overlapped flag is also setup.
The applications are compiled using Visual Studio 2008 and both processes are 32 bit.

Is there any limits that needs to be set up from Windows Server 2012 r2?Same behaviour is observed on Win Server 2016.

Thanks

Comment: Is the pipe created with PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE?  Is PeekNamedPipe succeeding and setting dwBytesLeft to 0 or is it failing?  Show the code that writes to the pipe.

Comment: Yes the pipe is created for message mode.PeekNamedPipe is successful and tells the correct number of bytes left.The problem is when we do the ReadFile the second time and then GetOverlappedResult the number of bytes received is 64k although the number of bytes as seen from PeekNamedPipe were reported more than 64k.  Also the other end where the data is written is just doing a writefile using overlapped io and GetOverlappedResult write all the bytes which it actually wanted to write.

Comment: You have comments before the second ReadFile that you're creating a new buffer of the appropriate length, but the second ReadFile appars to be using the original buffer which was originally created to be 64KB.

Comment: The initial buffer size can be changed via registry.In this example I have shown as 64*1024. Even if it is 1*1024,the second ReadFile operations stil reads 64k given that the original message was big enough.The new buffer for second Read is the buffer made by using the dwBytesLeft and the bytes read by first Read are copied to new buffer and the pointer adjusted to point where the second Read should fill the new buffer with remaining data.

Comment: Please note that this works if the client process is on a different machine which is Windows 7 64 bit for the same data size. If both processes are on windows server 2012 and if I reduce the data size to be with in limits of 64k+64k for both the ReadFile operations it also works.Also with large data it works on Win 2003 and 2008

Comment: The second GetOverlappedResult    call is also returing ERROR_IO_PENDING without reading all the data. What could be the possible reason for that?